# If $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and for every $x\in (0,1)$ exists $0<\delta \inf\{x,1− x\}$ with $f(x)=\frac{f(x−\delta)+f(x+\delta)}2$. How to show that $f(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

I saw this problem [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/IA/AnalysisI/2023-2024/Analysis%20Sheet%202.pdf) (7)

> Suppose that $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, and that for every
> $x \in (0, 1)$ there exists $0 < \delta < \inf\{x, 1 − x\}$ with $f(x) = \frac{f(x − \delta) + f(x + \delta)}2$. Show
> that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

I tried to prove this statement by setting $M :=\sup\{f(x)\} , \ m := \inf\{f(x)\}$ and proving that $f(a)= \frac{f(a-\delta_1)+f(a+\delta_1)}{2}=\frac{f(a-\delta_1 -\delta_2)+f(a+\delta_1-\delta_2)+f(a-\delta_1 +\delta_2)+f(a+\delta_1+\delta_2)}{4}=\dots$  will converge. The problem was I couldn't handle the sequences of deltas. There must be some trick in "$0 < \delta < \inf\{x, 1 − x\}$" but I couldn't found it. I tried to prove that eventually  that sequence of delta will make  $a+\sum_{k=0}^n \varepsilon_k \delta_k$ will converge to $0$ or $1$ where $\varepsilon_k \in \{-1,1\}$ for all $k$ but this didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is not identically zero. WLOG we can assume it is positive for some $x$. Then its maximum $M$, which is achieved, is positive. Let $f(x_0)=M$. Let $x_1= \sup\{x: f(x)=M\}$. By continuity, $f(x_1)=M$ and $x_1\in(0,1)$. Then we must have
$$
M=f(x_1)=[f(x_1-\delta)+f(x_1+\delta)]/2
$$
Which is clearly impossible because $f(x_1-\delta)\le M$ and $f(x_1+\delta)<M$ by definition of $x_1$.

Comment: Probably the condition on $\delta$ is given just to ensure that $0<x-\delta, x+\delta <1$. I guess the following statement too works (on seeing your proof): 

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Suppose, for each $x\in (0,1)$ it is true that there exist $a_x$ and $b_x$ with $0<a_x<x<b_x<1$ such that 
$$f(x) = \dfrac{f(a_x)+f(b_x)}{2}, $$
then $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I absolutely agree.